# Open and close div with scroll and fade when reached certain section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a responsive website where I have the below code that shows a div from the right of my window when he scrolls down but when he scrolls up the div shoiuld slowly fadeout and move to the right,
The issue is that sometimes it opens and sometimes it does not , there is no guarantee that my div will always open and close when it reaches a certain section
How will I achieve that

NOTE:The testAnim is called each time the user Scrolls but the div dones not open/close always, is it due to the fact that there may be too many scrolls happening?

```
if(true)
{
    if($('.container').css('display') == 'none' || 
       $('.container').css('width') == '0px'){
        testAnim();
    }
} else {
    if($('.container').css('display') == 'block'){
        testAnimBack();
    }
}

function testAnim() {
    $('.container').css('display','block').promise();
    $(".container").animate({  width: '21.16%',opacity:'1.0'}, 500).promise();
};

function testAnimBack() {
    $(".container").animate({  width: '0px',opacity:'0'}, 500).promise().done(function(){
        $('.container').css('display','none').promise();
    });
}
```

Comment: A fiddle please. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: _when it reaches a certain section_....explain bit more.

Comment: if(true) is the wrong way you are doing.

Comment: @Jai I have menus which just scroll down in the same page

Comment: @C-link  instead of true I have certain conditions they are alowas called when we scroll down so that is not the issue

Comment: so your if conditon is in `.scroll` function of jQuery right?

Comment: @Jai Yes it is in scroll the testAnim is called always in scroll but the divs do not always animate

Answer (score 0):

What seems to me you need to call your functions in `.scroll()` jQuery method:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > 100){ // check for the specific scroll top
       testAnim();
    }
});
```

then update your `testAnim()` function like this:

```
function testAnim() {
  if($('.container').css('display') == 'none' || 
     $('.container').css('width') == '0px'){
        $('.container').css('display','block');
        $(".container").stop().animate({  width: '21.16%',opacity:'1.0'}, 500);
  }else if($('.container').css('display') == 'block'){
        $(".container").animate({width: '0px', opacity:'0'}, 500, function(){
             $(this).css('display','none');
        });
  }
} // end of function
```

This way you don't need to write two separate functions.

Comment: the posted if condition is in a function that is called from   $(window).scroll(function()

Comment: also the testAnim is called each time there is a scroll but it does not always animate

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below, where I changed some logic.

http://jsfiddle.net/niyati999/gJwtH/2/

Javascript from the fiddle:

```
<script>
function test()
{
       if($('.container').css('display') == 'none' ||  $('.container').css('width') == '0px'){
            testAnim();
        }
    else if($('.container').css('display') == 'block'){
            testAnimBack();
        }


}
function testAnim() {
    $('.container').css('display','block').promise();
    $(".container").animate({  width: '21.16%',opacity:'1.0'}, 500).promise();
};

function testAnimBack() {
    $(".container").animate({  width: '0px',opacity:'0'}, 500).promise().done(function(){
        $('.container').css('display','none').promise();
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: it basically happens while scrolling not on button press